# Using CocoaPods and @IBDesignable together

Tags: swift, cocoapods, xcode-storyboard, xcode6

I have a project using @IBDesignable to control view properties from the Storyboard and everything is working correctly. However, if I integrate pods and add the bridging file as described here (https://medium.com/swift-programming/swift-cocoapods-da09d8ba6dd2) the Storyboard no longer displays correctly. It displays a blank view in the place where I had my custom view with @IBDesignable. The pods work correctly, just I can't see my changes in the Storyboard. Reverting my changes and removing the pods, solves the issue?

Is there anyway to use CocoaPods and @IBDesignable together, or is this just a bug in Xcode6?

Comment: Still a problem in Xcode 8.3.3. Added CocoaPods (Alamofire) breaks my @IBDesignable code (stuff that is not even dependent on Alamofire).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set the proper module name to your custom view in the storyboard?

```
org.cocoapods.XXX
```

[image]

if you have only XXX works but adding org.cocoapods. fixes a lot of issues.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want to support iOS versions below 8.0, you can have use_frameworks! in your pod file (as mentioned here http://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#use_frameworks_bang). What happen here is instead of making static libraries for your dependencies cocopods will make frameworks. IBDesignable will not break with frameworks.

Answer (score -4):

Try opening using xcodeproj instead of xcodeworkspace.  That worked for me.

Comment: That's not a solution, since you use the Workspace when using CocoaPods.